# Knox OpenID login infinite loop

Tags: openid, openid-connect, hydra, knox-gateway, apache-knox

I am trying to configure Apache Knox to use OpenID Connect (the ORY Hydra product).  The callback url is called, with the correct `code=` parameter, but then the login process loops ad infinitum.

I configured Knox according to this [Auth0 guide](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/171892/configure-knox-with-openid-connect.html) (same thing, just update the URLs).

The login process just loops.  I think Knox doesn't know what to do with the `code=` value, that is, how to exchange it for an `access_token` and `refresh_token`.  What am I doing wrong?  Using the wrong authentication type, the wrong callback url, something else?

Comment: Do you see hadoop-jwt cookie set in your browser ? also if you are using localhost or ip address this might not work.

Comment: Thanks, @SandeepMore, that led us to the the solution.  There was a missing configuration value.

Comment: Hello, I am having the same problem. How did you solve it? I hope it's not too late to ask, I'm going through the same thing, but I don't know what to do. I asked a question in case you want to see my problem and know how to solve it. Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73084041/infinite-loop-when-integrate-openid-in-nodejs

Comment: Sorry I don't remember and no longer have access to the code base. I remember it being fairly simple once we realized what we needed to do.